# Contiki: sky-shell-exec ELF_Loader error

Tags: shell, exec, elf, contiki

I'm trying to get the sky-shell-exec example working in Contiki.  To do this I am basically running the commands in the README that comes with the sky-shell-exec example.  The only thing I make sure to do that the README doesn't say is to do a "make compile-executable" before doing the "make upload-executable".  I am also always doing "sudo make …" since otherwise I get permission issues when trying to access the sky mote.  However, this all said, everything works up until I run "exec hello-world.ce".  When this runs I get a "Segment No Found" error.  I am currently trying to track the bug down in elfloader.c, but could use some help if anyone has seen this before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Have faced the same problem . Now it works, but you have to check for the compiler version you are using . when i was using "msp430-gcc (GNU GCC patched mspgcc-20110716) 4.5.3" it doesn't work and i have got errors like that, when i used msp430-gcc version 4.6.3 it works fine

Comment: Could you explain your process for changing compilers?  I am currently trying to do:
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade &&
sudo apt-get upgrade &&

curl -s http://adamdunkels.github.io/contiki-fork/mspgcc-4.7.0-compiled.tar.bz2 | tar xjf - -C /tmp/ && sudo cp -f -r /tmp/msp430/* /usr/local/ && rm -rf /tmp/msp430 && msp430-gcc --version || true

However this give errors when compiling.